# How to connect two wifi cards to the same wifi?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, gnome, networkmanager

I want to connect two wifi cards to a wifi hotspot. I have the necessary drivers installed and the NetworkManager GUI is able to recognize both cards. Both cards can also detect the target network. I select the target wifi on the first wifi card. It connects fine. Then I move to the second wifi card tab and select the target wifi. It also connects fine but then the first wifi card automatically disconnects. Is this by design? If not is there a command line method to do what I want?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by connecting two cards to the same hotspot simultaneously? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve the same goal: this sounds like [a possible XY problem.](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you think by doing this you will double the bandwidth, then you are mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not by design. The two cards should connect to the same hotspot and get two different IP addresses.

Did you check the settings of your WiFi cards? Are they trying to get the same IP?